# Error in finding the sum of diagonals of an array

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to find the sum of the diagonals for the following array seen below, but whenever I call the function `diagsfunc` and run the program it does not give the answer,

I made an if statement to make sure the array is a square matrix, and if it is, it proceeds to call the function `diagsfunc` where I find the sum of the diagonal elements however whenever I run it does not print the sum.

Below is the function, main and the array. all the other functions work fine except for the diagonal one. and in case you are wondering the file contains the following numbers, where the first 2 numbers are just the rows and columns and the last 2 numbers are specific rows and columns of the array used for functions:

The file contains:

```
4 4
5.5 7.8 7.8 3.3
2.2 1.1 4.4 7.7
9.9 7.6 4.4 6.6
9.0 4.0 5.0 2.0
2
3
```

The code:

```
/*Diagonal function*/
double
diagsfunc (double ** arr, int diagr, int diagc)
{
    int f, g;
    double sum3 = 0;

    for (f=0;f<diagr;++f)
    {
        for (g=0;f<diagc;++g)
        {
            if (f == g)
            {
                sum3 = sum3 + arr[f][g];
            }
        }
    }    

    return(sum3);

}

int
main (void)
{
    int cols, rows, i, j, nrows, ncols;
    double **a;
    double diag;
    FILE * fpointer;
    fpointer = fopen("projectfile.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fpointer, "%d %d", &rows, &cols);

    a = (double **) calloc (rows, sizeof(double *));

    for (i=0; i<rows; ++i)
        a[i] = (double *) calloc (cols, sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        for ( j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            fscanf(fpointer, "%lf", &a[i][j]);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        for ( j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
            printf("%10.3lf ", a[i][j]);
        }
            puts("");
    }

    fscanf(fpointer, "%d %d", &nrows, &ncols);

    if (rows == cols){
        diag = diagsfunc(a, rows, cols);
        printf("The sum of the diagonal elements is: %.3lf\n", diag);
    } else {
        printf("The array must be square to compute the sum of diagonals\n");
    }
    fclose(fpointer);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I recommend to [edit] the question for readability. Use some punctuation and some simple formatting (newlines). Currently you risk causing the "wall of text" impression.

Comment: Please check the return values of everything, especially the `fsanf()`s, the `fopen()`. Whereever you use a pointer, please provide reasoning that/why it cannot be NULL.

Comment: After reading in the array, try the simpler thing to just print it, then double check that this works as expected.

Comment: *it does not give the answer* what does that mean? You get the incorrect value or do you get *The array must be square to compute the sum of diagonals*?

Comment: Also you don't need the two loops for the diagonal, if the function is only called with a square matrix, then all you need is `double sum = 0; for(int i = 0; i < diagr; ++i) sum + = arr[i][i]`

Comment: in the case where the matrix is a square, it does not show anything when i run it, i figured out what was wrong though, thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a problem with "it does not show anything". What does that mean? The screen remains blank? You get an error message? What? And if it remains blank, then it is because you entered in an endless loop, see [achal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49846274/1480131) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few silly mistakes you did, lot more, but I am listing just required one

1. wrong variable used in the loop `for (g=0;f<diagc;++g)`.
   It should be

   `for (g = 0;g < diagc; ++g)`
2. to find sum of diagonal, you no need 2 loops as pointed by Pablo you can do using one loop itself as

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < diagr; ++i) { /* if its a square matrix */
           sum3 + = arr[i][i]      
   }
   ```

Complete Code

```
double diagsfunc (double ** arr, int diagr) {
        int f, g;
        double sum3 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < diagr; ++i) {
                sum3 += arr[i][i];
        }
        return sum3;
}
int main (void){
        int cols, rows, i, j, nrows, ncols;
        double **a;
        double diag;
        FILE * fpointer = fopen("projectfile.txt", "r");
        if(fpointer == NULL ) {
                /* put some message */
                return 0;
        }
        fscanf(fpointer, "%d %d", &rows, &cols);
        a = (double **) calloc (rows, sizeof(double *));
        for (i=0; i<rows; ++i)
                a[i] = (double *) calloc (cols, sizeof(double));
        for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                for ( j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
                        fscanf(fpointer, "%lf", &a[i][j]);
        for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
                for ( j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
                        printf("%10.3lf ", a[i][j]);
                }
                puts("");
        }
        //rewind(fpointer); /* this you forget */
        //fscanf(fpointer, "%d %d", &nrows, &ncols); /* why this statement ? */
        if (rows == cols){
                diag = diagsfunc(a, rows); /* no need to pass col value as its square matrix, both will be equal */
                printf("The sum of the diagonal elements is: %.3lf\n", diag);
        } else {
                printf("The array must be square to compute the sum of diagonals\n");
        }
        fclose(fpointer);
        return(0);
}
```

Also check all functions return value & learn how to debug your code.

Comment: I don't think that `rewind` should be used. If you look closer to the sample data, after the matrix there are 2 more values (2 and 3). I have no idea what they mean but these values might be what the OP is trying to read, so in that case the `rewind` is not necessary.

Comment: yes but thats `fscanf(fpointer, "%d %d", &nrows, &ncols);` is useless bcz OP is not using `nrows` & `ncols` anywhere. If OP wants to use later then it should be.

Comment: Thanks this is what helped, turns out I was just using an "f" instead of g, thanks for your help.